# How to say that creating account take place on a registration form?

Tags: phrase-request

I write user guide on English (foreign language to me).

Web Application have form on separate page for new user registration. I need to build sentence to say about this, but can't find right words.

I need something like this:

> Creating Gmail email take place on register form.

But it sounds badly.

Comment: We'll probably need a better idea of the context you need to use this phrase in. Is this the text of a link (or text that includes a link), a mention in a Frequently Asked Questions page, or what?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but you can say: ***Creating a Gmail account redirects you to the registration page/form.***

Comment: I agree with the others about clarity, but my best guess at what you're after would be something like:  **A Gmail address will be generated for you after completing the registration form.**  Honestly though, Stack Exchange may not be the best site for answering your questions.

Comment: You are not fluent in English and **should get someone fluent in English** to help you write the guide, because every single sentence of yours is bad English. "I **am writing a** user guide **in** English ... **A** web application **has a** form on **a** separate page for new user registration. I **want** to build ("construct" is better) **a** sentence to **say/convey this**, but can't find **the** right words. ... But it sounds **bad**" And it is.

Answer (score -1):

Create the Gmail account on the registration page...
The Gmail account will be created on the registration page...
Use the registration form to create the Gmail account...

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* these would be correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.